# Tasm gives an error for files with a longer name

Tags: windows, assembly, compilation, tasm

I tried to compile with tasm a file named addTwoNumbers.asm and I received an error 'Command Line: Can't locate file: addTwoNumbers.asm'. After I changed the name of the file to a shorter name like add.asm, it compiled without any error, Why ?

Comment: Which TASM version and which OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because TASM (even the last version) is a very DOS old program with no support for Windows LFN/VFAT/(call it what you want). It does only accept plain old DOS 8.3 file names.

One option to do something with that is to give TASM ADDTWO~1.ASM (assuming you have none other files with name beginning with AddTwo) as file name. Another - abandon long file names. The third - use something newer, perhaps MASM or FASM.